# I'm chopped. Yet, I'm joined

Tags: riddle

This is my first time I'm posting here. I hope you'll have fun!

> I'm chopped (in your view).
> But actually, I'm not.
>
> Sometimes, I bend my lower body (in your view).
> But actually, I don't.
>
> Who am I?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling :) This riddle seems to be too broad, can you add more lines to make it specific?

Comment: @ABcDexter Ok! Give me some time.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It could be

> an object which gives an image like this is a straw or rod in water due to refraction. From a lower angle it looks cut and from above bent.
>
>  [image]

Comment: Absolutely! Nice :)

Comment: FLash's answer was illuminating!

Comment: Brilliant @Tom.

Answer (score 11):

I actually thought these would also be cool to see

> When the shutter speed does not align with a moving object.
>  It can give a chopped, or sometimes bent object
>  [image]

Comment: Interesting! By the way, can you explain me how is this _chopped object_?

Comment: @rv7 This exact image isn't chopped, but you can imagine that if even less synched, the results would be chopped.

Comment: @rv7 The effect is called the Rolling Shutter Effect, when Minor, it causes this, when major (the objects are high speed), it can flat out cut objects in half or hide half of them.

Comment: @Ryan thanks for the _Rolling Shutter Effect_, I understood that this is also an answer. Heads up!

Answer (score 8):

I think it might be a

> rainbow 
> [image] 
> Is it?

Comment: No. But, you're closer.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be

> A lenticular print? (the gif might not show well)
>  [image]
>  
>  You can have a picture of a tree chopped and bent at one angle, but standing straight at another angle.

Answer (score 2):

It could be

> Chopsticks
>  Just used it for dinner. Chopped and also joined at end ? Or am I wrong ?
>
>   [image]

Comment: Hey richard, thanks for answering! I suggest you to provide an explanation also, as of why this answer fits into the riddle. Also, answers to riddle should not be exposed, you should use spoilers (`>!`) to hide them.